# Refresh table dynamically after client received data trough websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, datatables

good day peoples, i want to share about my problems, hopes this will help others with the same problem also. so how can i refresh the table data dynamically without the user refreshing the page. i tried to check if there is a data in the var responses, and if yes it will refresh the table. (the var response is where i get data, that was sent by the other client trough websocket).

this is what i have tried

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://10.43.4.52/websocket/');
    var tables = $('#description-table').DataTable();

    conn.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log('connected to websocket');
    };

    conn.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(e.data));
        var responses = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (responses.length > 0) {
            tables.ajax.reload();
        }
    };
```

Comment: `tables.ajax.reload()` would reload the table data from the configured AJAX data source. If you received the data you want to display, via the websocket already, then that probably doesn't make much sense here.